# GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) incorrectly evaluating to true

Tags: c++, .net, windows, keypress

I'm writing a simple program that records click positions and intervals between clicks. During the setup, the user presses 'ENTER' to add a new position to the list, and 'ESC' once they are done entering positions.

Some weird behavior I am getting is that other key presses cause `else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))` to evaluate as true incorrectly. My guess was that the 'ENTER' to end a `std::cin` was lingering in the buffer and causing that true, however I thought `std::cin.get()` and `std::cin.ignore` would have fixed that.

Why is it that keys other than 'ENTER' cause `(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))` to evaluate to true?

```
void initialSetup() {

    int temp = 0;
    char input;

    std::cout << "Unique sleep times? (y/n):  ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.ignore(100, '\n'); // discards the input buffer

    // Ask the user for a sleep each time, or use the same
    if (input == 'y') {
        uniqueSleepBetweenClicks = true;
    }
    else {
        // Sleep times are constant after each click
        std::cout << "Constant sleep time between clicks in ms:  ";
        std::cin >> constSleepBetweenClicks;
        std::cin.get();
        std::cin.ignore(100, '\n'); // discards the input buffer
    }

    std::cout << endl;
    std::cout << "***********************************" << endl;
    std::cout << "* 'ENTER' to set new position     *" << endl;
    std::cout << "* 'ESC' when done                 *" << endl;
    std::cout << "***********************************" << endl << endl;


    // Add new clicks to the sequence
    while (_getch()){

        Click click;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
            // Escape keypress ends adding new clicks
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)) {

            // Set the click position
            GetCursorPos(&click.point);
            std::cout << "Position set to (" << click.point.x << "," << click.point.y << ") " << endl;

            if (uniqueSleepBetweenClicks) {
                std::cout << "Sleep time in ms: ";
                std::cin >> click.sleep;
                std::cin.get();
                std::cin.ignore(100, '\n'); // discards the input buffer
            } 
            else { 
                click.sleep = constSleepBetweenClicks;
            }

            // Add to the list
            clickList.push_back(click);

        } 
    }
    return;
}
```

EDIT1: Replacing `VK_RETURN` with `VK_SPACE` makes the program work perfectly. The issue just seems to be with the ENTER key.

Comment: It seems that any key press other than escape counts as an enter.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the return value correctly, it does not return a BOOL! `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) < 0` or `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) > 0` depending on what you are checking for. Either way, `GetAsyncKeyState` is not the correct approach for a console application.

Use `ReadConsoleInput` to [handle input in a console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events).

If you want to capture input even when the user is working in another application you should use [hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) to capture mouse and keyboard events.

Comment: I chose `GetAsyncKeyState` because I need to read keypresses even if the console is not the active window.